# SQL Table Row Order

Tags: sql, row-number

Consider the following scenario:

I have two comma-separated strings of some table primary key Ids as
(`'1,2,3,4'` and `'2,3,4'`) in variables `@table1Ids` and `@table2Ids`.

Then I have the following lines:

```
SELECT 
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY GETDATE()) AS [ROW],
   ID 
INTO #table1Ids 
FROM ConvertCSVToBigIntTable(@table1Ids,',');

SELECT 
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY GETDATE()) AS [ROW],
   ID 
INTO #table2Ids 
FROM ConvertCSVToBigIntTable(@table2Ids,',');
```

I am doing this so that I get two tables out of the string values, which are passed as parameters to an SP.

But the order of tuples in `#table1Ids` and `#table2Ids` have to be intact as they are inter-related.

My question is that is there a chance that they get out of order.

**Note that `ConvertCSVToBigIntTable` is a built-in function that converts a comma-separated string into a table.**

Comment: What is 'out of order', you use getdate() that is current date. What ordered criteria do you expect?

Comment: That is, if `@table1Ids`='1,2,3' and `@table2Ids`='1,3,2', then `#table1Ids` must be:
ROW ID
1   1
2   2
3   3

and
`#table2Ids` must be:
ROW ID
1   1
2   3
3   2

My question is, by any chance would it come in a different order

Answer (score 0):

Why not just change your ConvertCSVToBigIntTable to add an identity column as the ID column of the table it creates from the CSV?

That way, you don't even need to do the ROW_NUMBER and can order by the identity.

Comment: That doesn't answer to the question. My question is whether they may come in a different order after being table-ized. Please answer yes or no, thank you!

Comment: Ok, in that case, yes they may come in different order.